# Pointing a domain to another hosting platform with including Cloudflare

Tags: dns, hosting, cloudflare

I have a 123-Reg domain name and need to point it at a new hosting provider. I have also added Cloudflare so I have changed the Nameservers on the domain to:

heather.ns.cloudflare.com
jeff.ns.cloudflare.com

In the Cloudflare DNS settings, I have changed the A records to the new hosting IP address.

However, it is still showing the old site and not the new one on the new hosting platform.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the real domain name?

Answer (score 0):

Once you change your A record, it could take some time to reflect the changes due to DNS cache. You could try using [Cloudflare's DNS resolver](https://1.1.1.1/) `1.1.1.1` or [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns) `8.8.8.8`, as they are usually faster than your ISP. Then do a `ping` to your domain to verify if the IP is updated or not.

You could also further verify your DNS records at [ViewDNS lookup](https://viewdns.info/dnsrecord/). If it's still not updated, perhaps provide us the actual domain name.